# Photo editing with url to get php

Tags: php, function, url, get, photo

Hello how can i include url function in photo

```
function photoUpload($file)
{
    $messages = '';
    $t = [];
    $i = 0;

    try {
        $input = array(
            'files' => $file,
            'type' => Input::get('type'),
            'max' => 1,
        );

        $files = array($input['files']);

        $image = \Image::make($file->getRealPath());
        $bigpath = public_path() . '/pictures/contentPhoto/big/';
        $mediumpath = public_path() . '/pictures/contentPhoto/medium/';
        $thumbpath = public_path() . '/pictures/contentPhoto/thumb/';
        $maxFile = $input['max'];
        $image->backup();
        $rules = array('file' => 'max:50000|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,jpg');

        if( !is_array($files) )
            return ['status'=>false, 'msg'=> 'Bir problem var!' ];

        if(count($files)>$maxFile)
            return ['status'=>false, 'msg'=> 'En az bir fotoğraf gerekli!' ];


        $status = array();

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $isim = md5(uniqid('', true));

            $t[]['org_name'] = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $t[$i]['extension'] = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $t[$i]['remote_name'] = $isim . '.' . $t[$i]['extension'];
            $t[$i]['path'] = $thumbpath;

            $t[$i]['remote_name'] = $isim . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $validator = Validator::make(array('file' => $file), $rules, [], ['file' => $file->getClientOriginalName()]);

            if ($validator->passes()) {

                $t[$i]['info'] = '<li>' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' bu fotoğraf yüklendi.' . '</li>';
                $t[$i]['result'] = true;
                $t[$i]['remote_full_name'] = Config::get('app.url') . '' . Config::get('app.pictures_db') . '/contentPhoto/thumb/' . $t[$i]['remote_name'];


                $status[] = 1;
                if (!file_exists(public_path().'/pictures/contentPhoto/')) {
                    mkdir(public_path().'/pictures/contentPhoto/', 0777, true);
                }

                $post_photo=$_FILES['files']['name'];
                $post_photo_tmp=$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

                $ext = pathinfo($post_photo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  // getting image extension

                list($width_min,$height_min)=getimagesize($post_photo_tmp); // fetching original image width and height

                $ratio = $width_min / $height_min;

                // Big Size
                $newwidth_min=700; // set compressing image width
                $newheight_min=($height_min / $width_min) * $newwidth_min; // equation for compressed image height
                $big = $image->resize($newwidth_min,$newheight_min);
                $big->sharpen(18)->save($bigpath.$t[$i]['remote_name'],60);
                $big->reset();


                if($ratio < 1) {
                    $t[$i]['ratio'] = false;

                    // Medium Size
                    $newwidth_min=320; // set compressing image width
                    $newheight_min=($height_min / $width_min) * $newwidth_min; // equation for compressed image height
                    $medium = $image->resize($newwidth_min,$newheight_min);
                    $medium->sharpen(8)->save($mediumpath.$t[$i]['remote_name'],60);
                    $medium->reset();

                    // Thumb Size
                    $newwidth_min=220; // set compressing image width
                    $newheight_min=($height_min / $width_min) * $newwidth_min; // equation for compressed image height
                    $thumb = $image->resize($newwidth_min,$newheight_min);
                    $thumb->sharpen(8)->save($thumbpath.$t[$i]['remote_name'],60);
                    $thumb->reset();

                } else {
                    $t[$i]['ratio'] = true;

                    // Medium Size
                    $targetHeight= 320;
                    $targetWidth = 240;
                    $imgWidth = $image->getWidth();
                    $imgHeight = $image->getHeight();
                    $verticalRatio = $targetHeight / $imgWidth;
                    $horizontalRatio = $targetWidth / $imgHeight;
                    $imgAvg = min($verticalRatio,$horizontalRatio);
                    $newHeight = $imgHeight * $imgAvg;
                    $newWidth = $imgWidth * $imgAvg;
                    $medium = $image->resize($newWidth,$newHeight);
                    $medium->fit(320,170)->sharpen(8)->save($mediumpath.$t[$i]['remote_name'],60);
                    $medium->reset();

                    // Thumb Size
                    $targetHeight= 320;
                    $targetWidth = 240;
                    $imgWidth = $image->getWidth();
                    $imgHeight = $image->getHeight();
                    $verticalRatio = $targetHeight / $imgWidth;
                    $horizontalRatio = $targetWidth / $imgHeight;
                    $imgAvg = min($verticalRatio,$horizontalRatio);
                    $newHeight = $imgHeight * $imgAvg;
                    $newWidth = $imgWidth * $imgAvg;
                    $thumb = $image->resize($newWidth,$newHeight);
                    $thumb->fit(320,170)->sharpen(8)->save($thumbpath.$t[$i]['remote_name'],60);
                    $thumb->reset();

                }

                $insertDb = DBDosya::insertPicture($file->getClientOriginalName(), $isim.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(), '' . Config::get('app.pictures') . '/', '.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension() );

                $t[$i]['id'] = $insertDb;


            } else {
                $t[$i]['result'] = false;
                $mesajlar = $validator->messages();
                $htmlMesaj = '';
                foreach ($mesajlar->all('<li>:message</li>') as $mesaj) {
                    $htmlMesaj .= $mesaj;
                }
                $t[$i]['info'] = $htmlMesaj;
            }

            $messages .= $t[$i]['info'];
            $i++;
        }
        $status = in_array(1, $status);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return ['status' => false, 'msg' => $messages . '<li>' . $e->getMessage() . '</li>',];

    }

    return ['status' => $status, 'msg' => $messages, 'data' => $t[0]];
}
```

It works properly in the files that come with this file. 
But I get getRealPath () error when I get photo with url.
How can I handle the photo from the URL with this function

Comment: Try to use the `file_get_contents()` function.

Comment: $filename= Input::get('incomingUrl');
photoUpload(file_get_contents($filename)); 
Not being the solution in this way